# If $A = [-5, 3)$ and $B = (1, \infty)$, is $3$ a member of $A \cap B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $A = [-5, 3)$ and $B = (1, \infty)$, what is $A \cap B$?

Since $3$ is not a member of $A$, do we include it in the intersection?

Comment: I think you should be able to answer your own question. What is the definition of the intersection of two sets? In other words, can you explain in words what $A \cap B$ means?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please read the tour guide to understand how to ask better questions. We also prefer questions that show a bit of effort in your thinking (e.g. show your work) and not just asking people to do homework-like problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might make more sense if you try to  visualise it. When you plot it on the number line, it will be clear to you. You should be getting $A\cap B$ to be $(1,3)$.

Answer (score 2):

We do not include it in the intersection because it is not a member of $A$, so it is not a member of both sets, so it is not in the intersection.